# The requested URL /accounts/registration/ was not found on this server

Tags: python, django, django-urls

What's wrong with my code? I have the next structure of my projects.

> /project/apps/accounts

in

> /project/project/urls.py

I have `url(r'^accounts/', include('apps.accounts.urls')),`
and in /project/apps/accounts/urls.py I have `url(r'^registration/', include('registration.backends.hmac.urls')),`
but when I try http://localhost:8000/accounts/registration/
 I have next error `The requested URL /accounts/registration/ was not found on this server.` Please help me.

Comment: I don't think you've given enough information to show what the problem is. The full error message tells you what URL patterns Django tried, which might give a hint what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Put `app_name='accounts'` variable in your `/project/apps/accounts/ulrs.py` file

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: Just write `app_name='accounts'` somewhere between your imports and `urlpatterns = []` inside of /project/apps/accounts/ulrs.py. Also, make sure all the apps you are using are in your `INSTALLED_APPS` inside `settings.py`.